# Getting highest value between 2 bars with bar index

Tags: pine-script

I would like to get the highest value between 2 bars with bar index

say I have 2 bar index 100 and 150.  I would like to get the highest value between these 2 candles.
How would I do so?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily as follows, let's denote your first bar index as `a` and the second one as `b` where `a < b`, the highest value within that range can be computed as follows:

```
highest = highest(close,b-a)
val = valuewhen(bar_index==b,highest,0)
```

with `val` returning the maximum value in range `[a,b]`. You can get the lowest value using the function `lowest` instead of `highest`.

In the case you want to find the highest value within two occurrences, you can use:

```
max = 0.
ma20 = sma(close,20)
ma50 = sma(close,50)
max := crossover(ma20,ma50) or crossunder(ma20,ma50) ? close : max(close,max[1])
```

here `max` is the current highest value, and reset when one of the conditions is true.

Comment: The ultimate goal for me is to find the highest price value between crossover and crossunder of sma20 and sma50.  I assigned the value of a and b using the function valuewhen(crossunder(xxx),xx,xx) .  Then I used your code and  got an error that "Invalid value of the 'length' argument in the 'highest' function.  it must be >0. "

Comment: remember that `a < b`, in the example you give `b = 150` and `a = 100`.

Comment: I assigned the value of a and b using the function valuewhen(crossunder(sma20,sma50),bar_index,0) and vice versa ...I don't know if it is the problem.

Comment: Alright, I understand your problem, I will edit my answer.

Comment: O..I understand 99% of it now, but what is the meaning of src in max(src,max[1])?

Comment: I apologize, I made a mistake, `src` shouldn't be there, I edited the answer.

Comment: Here i want to get the bar index of the highest between the two points. How do i do that?

Comment: And how I can get the max value corresponding bar_index?